# c# open resource image in default viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to take an image that I have added as a resource in Visual Studio and then open that image in the windows photo viewer.  I know if you place the image in a PictureBox, it is trivial to call that image from the PictureBox Image property. I can call the image from the code to open in the Windows viewer like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Guitar.jpg");
```

But I want to make it portable, such that the image will open up on any PC and the above method would only work from my PC.

I am thinking it has something to do with:

```
WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Resources.Guitar
```

but that is as far as I can seem to go......Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there is any way without saving it somewhere `Properties.Resources.Guitar.Save(filename)`

Comment: use relative path to make the app portable

Comment: Make sure that the image included in your project and use the "CopyLocal" propertyto make sure that it's always copied to the application folder on build, then you can just use relative path. Alternatively, you can dump it into a resource file that's part of you application and access it from within the resource file. Have a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292 and http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/Saveandloadimagefromresourcefile.htm as a start